# Transformar resultado de consulta a un entity en un array

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ado.net

en mi programa tengo un ADO.NET Entity Data Model con un par de tablas vinculadas a mi base de datos. Lo que quiero es realizar una consulta para traerme los datos de una tabla y poder acceder a ellos como si fuera un array.
Si por ejemplo en el entity hay una tabla que se llama Elemento que tiene las columnas IdElemento, Nombre, Descripcion e Imagen, mi intención es hacer una consulta sobre esa tabla para traerme un elemento con determinado Id, lo que realizo mediante el siguiente código:

```
int id = 34;    
var entidad = entidad.Elemento.First(x => x.IdElemento == id);
```

Ahora yo necesito poder acceder a sus atributos de la siguiente forma:

```
string nombre = entidad["Nombre"];
string desc = entidad["Descripcion"];
string img = entidad["Imagen"];
```

Para ser exactos, habría una variable, "columna", que contendría el valor del campo al que quiero acceder, por lo que se accedería así:

```
string valor = entidad[columna];
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo poder hacerlo?
Gracias.

Comment: necesitas hacerlo de esa manera por algo concreto? no podrías hacerlo de manera directa? `entidad.Nombre`

Comment: @miguel Si, necesito hacerlo de dicha forma porque luego será una variable la que me diga a qué elemento tengo que acceder.

Comment: entonces simplemente necesitas que dada una entidad y un nombre de propiedad, si esta existe como propiedad te devuelva el valor que tenga asignado?

Comment: @miguel Exacto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido hacerlo de la siguiente forma:
Tenemos instanciado nuestro ADO.NET Entity Data Model con el nombre ***entidades***. Supongamos que, de entre sus entidades, queremos acceder a la que tiene como nombre ***Elemento***. De dicha entidad queremos sacar el elemento que tiene como valor en su Primary Key un 2. Por último hay un string, ***columna***, el cual nos dice la propiedad del elemento que queremos sacar.
El código sería el siguiente:

```
object[] key = { 2 };
valor = typeof(Elemento).GetProperty(columna).GetValue(entidades.Elemento.Find(key));
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar  `Reflexion` para lograr lo que quieres, pero tienes que tener en cuenta que el uso sin control de `Reflexion` conlleva una gran pérdida de rendimiento. Si tienes que usarlo mucho, mi recomendación es que guardes las definiciones de propiedades en diccionarios estáticos por cada tipo que uses.

Te dejo una implementación de unas funciones en las cuales les pasas un objeto y el nombre de una propiedad  y si esta propiedad existe en el objeto y es pública, devuelve el valor de la primera propiedad que encuentre con ese nombre,

```
public object ObtenerValorPropiedadPorNombre(string nombrePropiedad, object contenedor)
{

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = contenedor.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public).Where(c => c.Name == nombrePropiedad);
    if (props.Count() != 0)
    {
        return props.First().GetValue(contenedor);
    }

    throw new Exception($"La propiedad {nombrePropiedad} no existe en el objeto {contenedor.GetType().Name}");

}
public T ObtenerValorPropiedadPorNombre<T>(string nombrePropiedad, object contenedor) where T : class
{

    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = contenedor.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public).Where(c => c.Name == nombrePropiedad);
    if (props.Count() != 0)
    {
        return props.First().GetValue(contenedor) as T;
    }

    throw new Exception($"La propiedad {nombrePropiedad} no existe en el objeto {contenedor.GetType().Name}");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea un diccionario y agrega cada propiedad del objeto al diccionario con su respectivo nombre/key/llave:

```
var elemento = eentidad.Elemento.First(x => == id);
Dictionary<string,string> elementoDic = new Dictionary<string,string>() { 
   { "Nombre", elemento.Nombre},
   { "Descripcion", elemento.Descripcion},
   { "Imagen", elemento.Imagen}
};

string nombre = elementoDic["Nombre"]; 
string desc = elementoDic["Descripcion"]; 
string img = elementoDic["Imagen"];
```

Sin embargo, utilizar las propiedades del objeto directamente seria mejor.

Comment: Esta solución no es válida porque todo esto se tendría que resolver en tiempo de ejecución y, en verdad, el nombre de las propiedades puede cambiar, por lo que no puedo crearme un diccionario previo para utilizarlo

Comment: Intenta para la proxima agregar toda la informacion relevante con claridad. Veo que [editaste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/95823/revisions) tu pregunta con nueva informacion explicando lo que en realidad querias.

Comment: De acuerdo, perdón por las molestias.